# multiple FXML Label, single MouseEvent handler

Tags: mouseevent, handler, fxml

I have the following FXML structure:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="menuPane">
  <children>
     <VBox>
       <children>
         <Label fx:id="Label1">   </Label> 
         <Label fx:id="Label2">   </Label> 
         <Label fx:id="Label3">   </Label> 

         <Label fx:id="Labeln">   </Label>
       </children>
     </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My question is: can I handle all the MOUSE_CLICKED events in one method, or do I need to write to every single label of them the following lambda?

```
LabelName.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, eventHandler->{});
```

For a couple Labels it is not a problem to write the lambda expressions, but when I start to get more labels, or if can/will add more Labels while the program running, I need a different approach.

I found an option here in stackoverflow, but I do not know what is the "scene" in my positions, as I have loaded the *mainScreen.fxml* , and in the MainScreenController I do not know how to get the scene.

```
     scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
      public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
       System.out.println("mouse click detected! " + mouseEvent.getSource());}
       });
```